# How to fix Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module and Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp.node' in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-install, sharp

I tried to install `expo` after I executed the command `exp start` but I got:

```
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp.node'.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you give me the complete url of module in the error text to help you? I had a similar problem and I resolved it.

Answer (score 50):

I encountered the identical issue, however, the execution of this single command line successfully resolved the problem at hand.

```
npm rebuild --verbose sharp
```

Please refer to the installation documentation under [Common problems](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#common-problems) for further guidance.

Comment: This fixed `Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-darwin-arm64v8.node'` for me on moving from a Intel to arm based Mac.

Comment: Worked for me on Linux (running with Multipass on a M1 Mac)

Answer (score 9):

Find the latest version of sharp and install it.

```sh
npm install sharp@0.28.3 --save
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I am not using expo but faced this issue in react native.
All I did is "deleted node_modules/sharp" folder.
run `npm install`.
fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes... you might even need to do it more than once, which was my case.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you configured npm to ignore installation scripts. In that case delete the sharp module and run:

```
npm install --ignore-scripts=false
```

Answer (score 2):

This causes after i updated, npm,angular version.

just try

```
npm i cordova-res
```

it solves above problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in mac when I update my developer tools using xcode-select install then node project stop working on local

1. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python3.8
2. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python3.9
3. rm yarn.lock
4. rm package-lock.json
5. rm -rf node_modules
6. brew upgrade
7. yarn install

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem and other solutions didn't solve it. Try to uninstall vips globally, it worked for me.

```
npm -g uninstall libvips
brew uninstall vips
```

Then:

```
yarn clean
yarn install
gatsby develop
```

Answer (score 0):

if trying some quick command fixes don't work you can try rebuilding the node_modules.

Delete the whole node_modules folder and run npm install

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading of `gatsby-transformer-sharp` helped me in my case.

Answer (score -3):

You may need to completely reinstall `expo-cli` package.

```
yarn global remove expo-cli
yarn global add expo-cli
```

OR

```
npm uninstall expo-cli -g
npm install expo-cli -g
```

(If you don't have `expo-cli` installed globally, remove `global` / `-f` flags)

Comment: What is the link between modules 'expo-cli' and 'sharp'?

Comment: @emeraldjava the question has an expo tag.